# Mounting a docker volume to a container on google cloud run?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I'm deploying a small web app as a docker container on Google Cloud Run. Since I'm working with multiple, large static files (language models, such as GPT-2) I've made changes to my dev environment so that the files are mounted as a volume to the container I'm developing in.

Now I'm confused if it at all is possible to host a docker volume on google cloud and then mount it to a container running on Google Cloud Run?

Or am I using the wrong Google service?

Sidenote: For this project I don't care about reliability and scaling.

Comment: Google Cloud Run does not support storage persistence or mounting volumes at this time. Based upon the limited details in your question, use Google Compute Engine.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Run does not yet support the volumes, as @John Hanley commented.

As a workaround, referring to this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/mount-a-file-as-a-volume-in-cloud-run-facc74c02cc6) about secret management on Cloud Run, you can deploy your Cloud Run service with the secret mounted as a volume.